# XSLT select, problem with double namespace

Tags: xslt, mapping, biztalk

when I use this xslt inline template on a BizTalk map

```xml
<xsl:template name="Test2">
    <xsl:param name="sale" />
    <xsl:variable name="promo" select="//s1:Sale[s1:ItemID = $sale]/s1:RetailPriceModifier[@MethodCode='Promotion' and @VoidFlag='false' and s1:ReasonCode= 'TRANSACTION_DISCOUNT']"/>
    <DISCOUNT_VALUE1><xsl:value-of select="$promo[1]/s1:Amount"/></DISCOUNT_VALUE1>
    <DISCOUNT_VALUE2><xsl:value-of select="$promo[2]/s1:Amount"/></DISCOUNT_VALUE2>
    <DISCOUNT_VALUE3><xsl:value-of select="$promo[3]/s1:Amount"/></DISCOUNT_VALUE3>
    <DISCOUNT_VALUE4><xsl:value-of select="$promo[4]/s1:Amount"/></DISCOUNT_VALUE4>
    <DISCOUNT_VALUE5><xsl:value-of select="$promo[5]/s1:Amount"/></DISCOUNT_VALUE5>
    <DISCOUNT_VALUE6><xsl:value-of select="$promo[6]/s1:Amount"/></DISCOUNT_VALUE6>
    <DISCOUNT_REASON1><xsl:value-of select="$promo[1]/s1:dtv:DiscountReasonCode"/></DISCOUNT_REASON1>
    <DISCOUNT_REASON2><xsl:value-of select="$promo[2]/s1:dtv:DiscountReasonCode"/></DISCOUNT_REASON2>
    <DISCOUNT_REASON3><xsl:value-of select="$promo[3]/s1:dtv:DiscountReasonCode"/></DISCOUNT_REASON3>
    <DISCOUNT_REASON4><xsl:value-of select="$promo[4]/s1:dtv:DiscountReasonCode"/></DISCOUNT_REASON4>
    <DISCOUNT_REASON5><xsl:value-of select="$promo[5]/s1:dtv:DiscountReasonCode"/></DISCOUNT_REASON5>
    <DISCOUNT_REASON6><xsl:value-of select="$promo[6]/s1:dtv:DiscountReasonCode"/></DISCOUNT_REASON6>
</xsl:template>
```

I receive the following error:

**Expected end of the expression, found ':'.
$promo[1]/s1:dtv -->:<-- DiscountReasonCode**

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

here an input example:

```
<RetailPriceModifier MethodCode="Promotion" VoidFlag="false">
                        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
                        <Amount Action="Subtract">1.98</Amount>
                        <PromotionID>3705:8604:</PromotionID>
                        <ReasonCode>DEAL</ReasonCode>
                    </RetailPriceModifier>
                    <RetailPriceModifier MethodCode="Promotion" VoidFlag="false">
                        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
                        <Amount Action="Subtract">0.38</Amount>
                        <PromotionID>3706:8605:</PromotionID>
                        <ReasonCode>DEAL</ReasonCode>
                    </RetailPriceModifier>
                    <RetailPriceModifier MethodCode="Promotion" VoidFlag="false">
                        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
                        <Amount Action="Subtract">0.40</Amount>
                        <PromotionID>TRANS_PCT_PROMPT</PromotionID>
                        <ReasonCode>TRANSACTION_DISCOUNT</ReasonCode>
                        <dtv:DiscountReasonCode>DC4</dtv:DiscountReasonCode>
                    </RetailPriceModifier>
```

the output should be:

<DISCOUNT_VALUE1>0.40</DISCOUNT_VALUE1>
<DISCOUNT_REASON1>DC4</DISCOUNT_REASON1>

thanks and regards

Comment: Element names such as `s1:dtv:DiscountReasonCode` with a colon after the namespace prefix are not allowed.

Comment: That XPath is incorrect. What does the source XML look like? What are you attempting to target?

Comment: Why do you use the `s1:` prefix in your template at all, then?

Comment: without /s1: I receive this error: Prefix 'dtv' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The `DiscountReasonCode` elements are in the `dtv` namespace.

Remove the `sv1:` prefix from those XPaths targeting the `DiscountReasonCode`.

The XPath should be: `$promo[1]/dtv:DiscountReasonCode`

Comment: without /s1: I receive this error: Prefix 'dtv' is not defined.

Comment: Define it, then. There has to be a way to declare what namespace-uri maps to your namespace-prefix. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/namespace-management

Comment: the dtv namespace is already defined on input xsd schema

Comment: But you need to declared and available for the process that is querying, in order to use a namespace-prefix in your XPath. You could also match generically on an element and filter based upon `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` inside of a predicate filter i.e. `$promo[1]/*[local-name() = 'DiscountReasonCode']`

Comment: with $promo[1]/*[local-name() = 'DiscountReasonCode'] it works :)